# Convert 2 rows with multiple columns into 2 columns with multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I often run ad-hoc queries in SQL Server 2005/2008 where I would like to convert two rows in multiple columns into multiple rows having only two columns.

Given a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN created_at IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS 'TOTAL'
    , SUM(CASE WHEN created_at > '2013-07-15' THEN 1 END) AS 'CREATED W/I LAST YEAR'
    , SUM(CASE WHEN updated_at > '2013-07-15' THEN 1 END) AS 'MODIFIED W/I LAST YEAR'
    , SUM(CASE WHEN updated_at < '2011-07-15' THEN 1 END) AS 'UNTOUCHED OVER 3 YEARS'
    , SUM(CASE WHEN updated_at < '2009-07-15' THEN 1 END) AS 'UNTOUCHED OVER 5 YEARS'
    -- , often there are more columns
FROM 
    mytable
WHERE
    < filtering >
```

I would like it to display something like this:

```
TOTAL: 5000
CREATED W/I LAST YEAR: 500
MODIFIED W/I LAST YEAR: 1500
UNTOUCHED OVER 3 YEARS: 2000
UNTOUCHED OVER 5 YEARS: 1000
```

I want to keep DRY and not string together a bunch of SELECTs with UNIONs. I have never used PIVOT, UNPIVOT or CROSS APPLY. Most of the examples I have seen for UNPIVOT don't seem to apply to queries like the one above - or am I must missing something? It seems simple enough but "I'm just not getting it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH t AS (
    SELECT 
        SUM(CASE WHEN created_at IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS 'TOTAL'
        , SUM(CASE WHEN created_at > '2013-07-15' THEN 1 END) AS 'CREATED W/I LAST YEAR'
        , SUM(CASE WHEN updated_at > '2013-07-15' THEN 1 END) AS 'MODIFIED W/I LAST YEAR'
        , SUM(CASE WHEN updated_at < '2011-07-15' THEN 1 END) AS 'UNTOUCHED OVER 3 YEARS'
        , SUM(CASE WHEN updated_at < '2009-07-15' THEN 1 END) AS 'UNTOUCHED OVER 5 YEARS'
        -- , often there are more columns
    FROM 
        mytable
    WHERE
        < filtering >
)
SELECT name, value
FROM t
UNPIVOT(value FOR name IN (
    [TOTAL]
    , [CREATED W/I LAST YEAR]
    , [MODIFIED W/I LAST YEAR]
    , [UNTOUCHED OVER 3 YEARS]
    , [UNTOUCHED OVER 5 YEARS]
)) p
```

Comment: Perfect! I knew it had to be that simple. Thanks!!